# I need to connect google time zone api to this

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-api, google-geocoding-api

I'm trying to make a webpage with a button. When the button clicked the webpage has to display the user's current location and the user's timezone.
I'm locating users' latitude & longitude by jquery and for the location name I use reverse geocoding of google geocode API and for timezone google timezone API.
Function for the latitude & longitude and function for the reverse geocoding works well. But the function for the timezone isn't working. The unworking function I wrote for this API is the last function in the JS code.  
I don't understand how to solve this problem.
I need someones' help with this.

HTML Part

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello let's trace your location</h1>
    <button onClick="getLocation()">Get Location</button>
    <div id="output"></div>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="java.js">
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS PART

```
var x = document.getElementById('output');
function getLocation(){
    if (navigator.geolocation){
        x.innerHTML = "Supporting";
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
    else{
        x.innerHTML = "Browser not supporting";
    }
}
function showPosition(position){

    var locAPI = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+position.coords.latitude.toFixed(6)+","+position.coords.longitude.toFixed(6)+"&key=<key>";
    //x.innerHTML += locAPI;
    $.get({
        url: locAPI,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var num = data.results.length - data.results.length;
            var add1 = data.results[num].address_components.length - 1;
            var add2 = data.results[num].address_components.length - 2;
            x.innerHTML = num;
            x.innerHTML += add1;
            x.innerHTML += add2;
            x.innerHTML += data.results[num].address_components[add2].long_name;
            x.innerHTML += "<br/>";
            x.innerHTML += data.results[num].address_components[add1].long_name;
        }
    });
}

function showPosition(location){

    var timeAPI = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location="+location.coords.latitude.toFixed(6)+","+location.coords.longitude.toFixed(6)+"&amp;timestamp=<key>";
            //x.innerHTML += timeAPI;
            
            $.get({
                url:timeAPI,
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
}
}
```

Comment: You'd need to specify how its not working, otherwise we arent able to help you. What error/result are you getting when calling this function?

Comment: You can't have two functions named the same.. Name the time zone one something different and call it from `showPosition`.

Comment: [Relevant docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/overview). I see you use `<key>` as placeholders.

Comment: @sharpness I won't get any kind of error. But when running the application timezone API also has to log its data to the console same as the geocode API. But it's not happening.

Comment: @HereticMonkey What do mean call it from `showPosition`

Comment: @A1rPun placeholder <key> is where API credentials have to type.

Comment: Rename the second `showPosition` to `getTimeZone`. On the second line of the first `showPosition(position)`, write `getTimeZone(position);`.